# How do I echo the data-type="address"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get a javascript onclick to work the plan is when the user clicks a div with the class="store box" it will echo the  which is within that div see example:

```
<div 
onclick="javaclick()"
data-type="store" 
class="store box"
data-latitude="53.7658344" 
data-longitude="-2.6646485">
<p>
    <span class="title" data-type="title">Store38</span>,<br>
    <span data-type="address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 123 Barrington Road, Barrington, BR1 2JH</span>,<br>
    <span data-type="phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 00000 000000</span><br>
    <span data-type="openingtimes"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Opening Times: <?php include('store-hours.php'); ?></span>
    <br>

    <span data-type="directions" class="directions">
        <label data-type="directions-label">Get directions</label> 
        <input data-type="directions-input" type="text" class="hidden" />
    </span>
</p>
```

so when the user clicks the div in this case store38, it will write the address from data-type address in the div footer_box.

```
<div id="footer_box">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function javaclick(){
                 document.write("data-type='address'");
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

and it would do it for each of the stores i have 50 in total. any ideas?

Comment: Tagged jQuery, so something like `$('.store.box').click(function() { $('#footer_box').text($('[data-type=address]', $(this)).text()); });`?

Comment: near enough yeh when the user clicks one of the 50 divs it will echo the data-type="address" from the div they clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery, you can do something like this:

```
$(".store").click(function(){
    address = $(this).find('[data-type=address]').text();
    $("#footer_box").html(address);
});
```

Demo [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VuL7V/)

Comment: now if i had data-type=image and had an <img src="image"/> would i just need to change the data-type=address to image and then it would work or would i need to change some other stuff ?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to outputting data from JS is to write it into some div.

```
<div id="Output"> </div>
```

jQuery function

```
$("#output").text("works");
```

Or pure JS solution

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHtml = "works";
```

To get that data you will need jquerys `.data()` or `.attr()` function:

```
var data = $(element).data("type");
```

Or:

```
var data = $(element).attr("data-type");
```

To handle it in function, you must transfer `element` variable.

```
function javaclick(element) {

}
```

And bind event:

```
$(".store").bind("click", function(event){
    /* code */
});
```

Now just assemble that, and you have got solution.

```
$('.store.box').click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data("type");
  $('#footer_box').text(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking some javascript from HTML, contain that logic in your JS instead. Example:

```
(function() {
    var footerBox = document.querySelector('footer_box');
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.store.box'), function(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            footerBox.innerHTML = e.target.dataset.type;
        }, false);
    });
})();
```